# Add domain to all vimeo videos by API

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

We need to add domains to all of our videos. But I cant find a API call to add a domain to all of the videos - only one video at a time.

Right now I am doing two steps:
https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos....
Here I get all of our videos and their IDs and a hell of lot of stuff I dont need.

Then I loop through all of the videoIDs and call
https://api.vimeo.com/videos/{videoId}/privacy/domains/{newDomain} for each video.

This results in 1200 put requests which is not good. Furthermore I am not sure if we get banned with to many requests.

Is there som APIs that I have missed which supports what I am trying to do ?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the documentation I found an option for reducing the amount of data return. By adding e.g. &fields=uri,privacy to my api calls I reduced the amount of data returned.

I still have to loop each video and do a put however the first step is a lot faster.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the API to do this, I suggest setting the default video privacy for all your videos at https://vimeo.com/settings/videos/upload_defaults - this includes the ability to add domain privacy.

Comment: This actually works, but what they don't inform you is that the changes apply asynchronously, meaning it will take some time for the changes to be applied to all of your videos